# How did the sponsor xMatters contribute to this year's Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

It's the first time ever that Winter Bash has a sponsor. From the [announcement blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021/):

> First, we want to introduce [xMatters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021/), an Everbridge company, as our sponsor for Winter Bash 2021. If you’re not familiar with their technology, they offer a service reliability platform that helps DevOps, SREs, and operations teams automate workflows, ensure infrastructure and applications are always working, and rapidly deliver products at scale. Please join us in thanking them for their support!

I'm just wondering, in what ways, if any, did xMatters contribute to this year's Winter Bash?

Comment: cold hard dollars would be my guess.

Comment: @Luuklag nothing comes for free, so I bet they also had some effect on the hats and triggers, and maybe more things. The glaring silence from SE side only means it's probably true.